# Paramiko -Python 3 local ssh to mac OSX

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Thank for reading this.

### Objectif

Using Python3, I want to send SSH command to my local Mac osx computer. After research, I found Paramiko to help me but I'm open to other librairies

### Setup

Both computer, (my windows computer and the target mac osx computer) have Private Key/ Public key known from each other, so to resume, I can ssh manually without password and it works.
I'm using only python 3 to do the operations.

### Attempt

You can find my following code below :

```
import paramiko

hostname = 'MyUser@macbook-air-de-louis.home'
port = 22
username = 'MyUserName'
pkey_file = 'C:/Users/MyUserName/.ssh/id_rsa'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(pkey_file)
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.load_system_host_keys()
    s.connect(hostname, port, pkey=key)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command('ifconfig')
    print(stdout.read())
    s.close()
```

### Result error

The following error is below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jr.py", line 23, in <module>
    s.connect(hostname, port, pkey=key)
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 329, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 200, in _families_and_addresses
    hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

### EDIT

Special Thank to @Kenster
I changed by the IP address and i have this following error, 
Do you know what I miss ?

```
    s.connect(hostname, port, pkey=key)
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 424, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 714, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 691, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_publickey(username, key))
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1450, in auth_publickey
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "D:\Documents\ana\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 226, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

```
hostname = 'MyUser@macbook-air-de-louis.home'
username = 'MyUserName'
...
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

The hostname that you're using, `MyUser@macbook-air-de-louis.home`, isn't valid. Your script is trying to resolve your hostname into an address and failing. It appears that you've prefixed it with the username and that's not correct.

Try using "macbook-air-de-louis.home" as the hostname, without the "MyUser@" part. If that still doesn't work, try using the IP address of the remote system.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer, i chaned directly by the IPV4 of the mac and now it just say : Authentification failed, i tried by my own with a classic ssh command and it works, so i don't know what's wrong now ?